# NativeScript, Angular, HttpClient get Headers : result.headers = undefined

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I need to get HTTP headers from a NativeScript/Angular application.
The resulted Json is fine but not the headers.
  -> result.headers = undefined
I have posted a sample of the project at 
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Saa7h7&v=3

The HTTP service is defined in data-items.service.ts and the calling component is home.component.ts

I have to mention that telnet shows up the custom  header:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 41971
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

> > > > > token: 123456 <<<<<<
> > > > >           X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
> > > > >           X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
> > > > >           Date: Thu, 21 Mar 2019 16:24:53 GMT

Please advice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer using

return this.http.get(this.serverUrl, { headers: options, observe: "response" });

instead of

return this.http.get(this.serverUrl, { headers: options });